# Variable scope in php in 2 block codes

Tags: php

In a webpage in top i use this code:

```
<?php
switch ($urlcomecatid) {

case "95":
$target_cat1='96';
$target_cat1_name = "A";
break;

case "96":
$target_cat1='95';
$target_cat1_name = "B";
break;
?>
```

and in another down part the page i use these variable

```
<?php
echo "<p class='pagefooterlifestyle' align='center'>
<a href='../lifestyle/lifestylesub.php? catid=$target_cat1'>$target_cat1_name</a></p>";
?>
```

BUT i get error undefined variable for 
$target_cat1
$target_cat1_name

please let me know that what is the problem?

Comment: What if `$urlcomecatid` doesn't contain either `95` or `96`?

Comment: I'd guess that $urlcomecatid is neither 95 nor 96. You should add some kinda default value. Also let me just say - the seconds snippet is just awful.

Comment: $urlcomecatid may not have matched any of the cases given in the switch;

Comment: Yes $urlcomecatid has value

Comment: The send block codes works but in error_log file i see that i have error for these variable.

Comment: In error_log file it write :Undefined variable: target_cat1

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your variables:

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {

case "95":
$target_cat1='96';
$target_cat1_name = "A";
break;

case "96":
$target_cat1='95';
$target_cat1_name = "B";
break;

default:
$target_cat1 = '';
$target_cat1_name = '';
}
```

You must be prepared for different values for `$urlcomecatid` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$urlcomecatid` variable contains neither 95 nor 96, PHP will ignore both cases, so the `$target_cat1` and `$target_cat1_name` variables won't be initialized.

You can use `default` to tell PHP what to do when all cases are ignored.
http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php